# How to align vertical elements as horizontal elements and shift to right side of the screen using CSS?

Tags: css

I am working on a plugin and need to align some social buttons to right side using CSS. But instead of showing in a line (horizontally) the buttons are showing vertically. Here's the code for that.

```
<div class= "sc1"><div class= "sc2"><span>Connect with us:</span> 
<div class= "sc3"><a href="http://www.facebook.com"><div class="facebook-icon"></div></a>
<a href="http://www.twitter.com"><div class="twitter-icon"></div></a>
<a href="http://www.google.com"><div class="google-icon"></div></a>
<a href="http://www.instagram.com"><div class="instagram-icon"></div></a></div></div></div>
```

Now the CSS

```
    .sc1 {
    margin: 5px 0px;
    background-color: #3498DB;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 8px 10px;
    width: 100%;
}
.sc2{
    float: right;
    color: white;
}
.sc3 {
    float: right;

}
.sc3 .facebook-icon {
    background-image: url(images/social-connections-icons.png);
    height: 32px !important;
    width: 32px;
    background-position: 0 0;
    /*float: right;*/
}
.sc3 .twitter-icon {
    background-image: url(images/social-connections-icons.png);
    height: 32px !important;
    width: 32px;
    background-position: -32px 0px;
    /*float: right;*/
}
.sc3 .google-icon {
    background-image: url(images/social-connections-icons.png);
    height: 32px !important;
    width: 32px;
    background-position: -125px 0px;
    /*float: right;*/
}
.sc3 .instagram-icon {
    background-image: url(images/social-connections-icons.png);
    height: 32px !important;
    width: 32px;
    background-position: -63px 0px;
    /*float: right;*/
}
```

But after this the code final result is showing as

[Here's the picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5IPWG.png)

I have also uploaded complete code on GitHub, in case someone wants to look at the complete code. [Here it is.](https://github.com/gurjyot/Social-Connections)

Comment: Try adding `display: flex;` to your `.sc3` class

Comment: It worked like a charm man. Thanks a lot... :)

Comment: Awesome! You mind if I put in in an answer and you can approve it? :)

Comment: I cannot give it a vote bro since I do not have the required points. But I made your answer the best answer.

Comment: No worries man, haha. Thanks for approving it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add `display: flex;` to your `.sc3` class:

```
.sc3 {
  display: flex;
}
```

This will make all the icons align horizontally.